# Do I have to resize all of the image before put them into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am new to html&css. I am trying to build a simple website using HTML and CSS just to display the products for my business. On my content page, I want to place 2 different product pictures next to each other. I tried to resize the images (using an image editing tool) exactly the same size to one another before input them into the divs in my HTML and it worked. But if I did not resize before placing my image into my HTML, I would encounter the following problem:

I tried to set both the %width and %height of the images **(different size)** within a `div`. **It worked** in the sizing part **but it also distorted** the image. If I only set the %width or %height, then the other dimension does not equal to each another. So every time I use images, I have to make sure their size is the same before placing them into my HTML right? Is there any way I can use CSS to resize images and not distort them?

Extra question: is there a common height of the image for product display in both phone screen and desktop screen? I used `rem` but I am not sure is it the right unit to use.

Thank you so much!!

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height:15rem;
    position: relative;
    top:5vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.product{
    width:48%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.product img{
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="product">
        <a href="#"><img src="./Image/1.jpeg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="product">
        <img src="./Image/2.jpeg">
    </div>
</div>
```

I place the image inside the div next to each other like this:

[image: Place images next to each other]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Options:

Make them background images with `background-size` set to `cover`

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height:15rem;
    position: relative;
    top:5vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.product{
    width:48%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
            background-position:center center;
}

.product img{
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="product" style='background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624743890649-ca317cf9a0fc?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60)' >
    </div>

    <div class="product" style='background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624746068623-d3f9c4ce5739?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60)'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, keep them as `<img>` elements and use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 5vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.product {
  width: 48%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}

.product img {
  margin: auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* or cover, contain... */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="product">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624743890649-ca317cf9a0fc?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624746068623-d3f9c4ce5739?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
</div>
```

Regarding the extra question, I prefer to use [viewport-units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

Comment: Thank you so much, I need your help to clarify one more thing from the second option. I know that the **flex-grow** applies to the elements in the div, but since there is only 1 image inside the div, what is the reason for setting flex-grow: 0 for the product img? Is it by default that the browser already set it to 0?

Comment: Im not sure why that is in my code! I think it was accidental :) and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [object-fit property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) used to resize an image to fit into its container without distoring the image